# Solving $x+y+z+u+t=0$, $x^3+y^3+z^3+u^3+t^3=0$, $x^5+y^5+z^5+u^5+t^5=-10$

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations, roots, symmetric-polynomials, chebyshev-polynomials

Find all real numbers $x$, $y$, $z$, $t$, $u$ that

$x+y+z+u+t=0$

$x^3+y^3+z^3+u^3+t^3=0$

$x^5+y^5+z^5+u^5+t^5=-10$

I'm learning about Chebyshev polynominals but in this case, I still haven't got any idea :(( please help me

Comment: what kind of numbers are this?

Comment: they are real of cause

Comment: I am not sure whether it helps, but there is a question about very similar system, but with the restriction that the 5 numbers are from the interval $[-2,2]$: [A system of equations with 5 variables: $a+b+c+d+e=0$, $a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3+e^3=0$, $a^5+b^5+c^5+d^5+e^5=10$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/162854), Found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24x%2By%2Bz%2Bu%2Bt%3D0%24%2C%20%24x%5E3%2By%5E3%2Bz%5E3%2Bu%5E3%2Bt%5E3%3D0%24%2C%20%24x%5E5%2By%5E5%2Bz%5E5%2Bu%5E5%2Bt%5E5%3D-10%24&p=1).

Comment: thanks, it's helped me so much :))

Comment: however, I still have one more question, that when we know that the sum of cos5a = 5, how to do next

Answer (score 0):

There are many real solutions. To obtain examples, we choose, say, $x=-2$ and $y=3$.
Taking resultants we obtain the equation
$$
3u^3+3u^2-19u-1=0,
$$
and $z$ as a root of a quadratic equation in $u$. Now there are three real solutions, e.g., $u=2.09659797695$. Then 
$$
(x,y,z,u,t)=(-2,3,- 3.04437453374,2.09659797695,- 0.0522234432082)
$$
is a solution.

Comment: yes that right, but what we need to do here is figure out the form of each number

Comment: of course with 5 unknowns and just 3 equations, we can't do more

Comment: You could edit the question to say more on what we need to do here.